# Проектирование базы данных (трёхмерной)

Tags: база-данных, sqlite

В моём приложении пользователь может решать вопросы из разных категорий. В приложении должна присутствовать возможность сохранения статистики. Для каждой категории нужно хранить статистику для некоторого количества раундов. В каждом раунде нужно хранить статистику для некоторого количества вопросов.

Вопрос в том, как организовать структуру базы данных. Я вижу два варианта: можно для каждой категории сделать свою таблицу, в которой для каждого раунда будет сохраняться имя таблицы для статистики раунда; другой вариант: организовать одну больную таблицу вопросов, в которой среди полей будут присутствовать `id` категории и `id` раунда.

Мне кажется, что второй вариант обладает меньшей производительностью, однако первый вариант, кажется, нарушает некие каноны проектирования баз данных.

Приложение пишу с использованием базы данных `SQLite`.

Comment: Возможно, я ошибаюсь, но мне кажется, что Вы зря себя накручиваете. Разница в быстродействии будет минимальна, если в таблицах завести индексы по: `id` категории, `id` раунда, `id` вопроса... Первый вариант требует 2 отдельных запроса, а второй позволит получить данные в 1 запрос. И только эксперимент на достаточно больших объёмах данных покажет, что быстрее

Comment: @velial Можно же сделать (`id` категории, `id` раунда, `id` вопроса) первичным ключом, да? В таком случае же автоматически будет создан индекс по этим трём полям. Не лучше ли создать такой индекс: (`id` раунда, `id` категории, `id` вопроса) ?

Comment: Да, первичный ключ означает автоматическое создание уникального индекса. Порядок столбцов в индексе выбирайте такой, с каким удобнее работать. На всякий случай напомню, что если индекс по (`id` раунда, `id` категории, `id` вопроса), а Вы хотите выбрать все вопросы по `id` категории из всех раундов, то индекс задействован не будет. В то же время, если выбирать все вопросы по `id` раунда, индекс будет использован. Т.е., по индексу запрос пойдёт тогда, когда в условии используются 1-е `k` столбцов индекса (1<=k<=3). Впрочем, никто не запрещает создавать дополнительный индекс по `id` категории.

Comment: @velial из таблицы определённой категории с раундами я получаю `id` раунда, `id` категории мне известен, получается, мне известны первые два поля индекса (`id` раунда, `id` категории, `id` вопроса), поэтому он будет использован. Кажется, так.
Просто мне кажется, что этот индекс будет наиболее эффективен, так как определённому раунду соответствует меньше вопросов, чем определённой категории.